# How do I use a non-stretchable, but repeating background image for UISlider track?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uislider

Is it possible to set a track image for the `UISlider` which does not strech, but repeats itself?

I have a background image with small position points (the attached image is exmaple... mine is horizontal). So if the `UISlider` is longer than the image itself, it starts to stretch it and the position points are not symmetrical any more.  Would be really nice that if the slider or the thumb exceeds track image width, then it just repeats itself.

Something similar to css `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the background colour to [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:yourImage];?

Comment: It changes the colour insite the slider. i.e. all the borders and height are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a).

It only works on iOS 5 and later though.